# Rotating 2D-Projectile towards mouse, hides the projectile (Maybe changes the layer)

Tags: 2d, unity, shooter

I want to shoot towards my mouse, which is working fine now. After this was solved, I wanted to rotate the projectile, so that it's looking to the mouse. This is my code:

```
projectile.transform.LookAt (target);
```

I think this should work, but suddenly my projectile is gone, I can still see the particles behind it but the projectile for itself isn't visible. So I think, that it switched to another layer. Target looks like this:

```
Vector2 target = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (new Vector2 (Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y));
```

So it shouldn't be possible that the z value is wrong am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually when a texture is hidden in a 2D game, it's because it goes "in the back" of the screen. When you do lookAt(target), you have to remember that a Vector2 is just a vector3 with z=0 (thus, if you have z=1 for your background for example, it might go behind).